# Trouble Installing Google Chrome on Fedora 24

Tags: google-chrome, fedora

I've recently installed Fedora 24 on my laptop, and have been trying to get Google Chrome on it ever since. I've followed this instructions on this website:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-google-chrome-with-yum-on-fedora-red-hat-rhel/

which basically tells me to add the repository first as root and then install chrome using dnf. However when I attempt to do this I get the error:

Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:32 ago on Wed Oct 12 17:06:19 2016.
No package google-chrome-stable available.
Error: Unable to find a match.

I've also tried to do this after dnf update and rebooting.
I've also downloaded the rpm from google itself, but get the error " This package is not installable"

I'm not sure exactly what to do now.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to your current browser, probably Firefox. Search for: install google chrome.

Next on the download page for Google Chrome you click download.

https://www.google.nl/chrome/browser/desktop/

Then select the RPM file instead of the DEB file, download it and install using YUM Extender. (just double click the downloaded file). From here you'll be prompted for your password and you can install Chrome.

That brings me to my next question: Did you make yourself admin when installing the system? Or is there at least a root password set?

Quick sidenote though, Google stopped supporting 32 bit for their browser. If you use a 32 bit OS that will give problems too.